# Error 'no provider for Http' al hacer peticion GET - Ionic 2

Tags: http, ionic2

Tengo un `Runtime Error` con el método `get` de `Http` y no se por que, quien me pueda ayudar le agradezco, el error es el siguiente:

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!
>   Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1583:86) at noProviderError
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1621:12) at
>   ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3122:19) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3161:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3093:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:2962:21)
>   at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:220:110)
>   at AppModuleInjector.getInternal
>   (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:343:54) at
>   AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3908:44) at resolveDep
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11276:45)

los codigos son

***src/providers/servi-productos.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the ServiProductos provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ServiProductos {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ServiProductos Provider');
  }


  getMyJson(){
    this.http.get("assets/json/data.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

***src/app/app.module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { Perfil } from '../pages/perfil/perfil';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ServiProductos } from '../providers/servi-productos';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Perfil,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      //backButtonText: 'Volver',
      iconMode: 'ios',
      modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
      modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
      pageTransition: 'ios-transition'
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Perfil,
    ListPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ServiProductos,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

***src/page/perfil/perfil.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ServiProductos } from '../../providers/servi-productos';

/**
 * Generated class for the Perfil page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-perfil',
  templateUrl: 'perfil.html',
})
export class Perfil {
    login: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};
  submitted = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public serviProduct: ServiProductos) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Perfil');
    this.serviProduct.getMyJson();
  }

}
```

***src/assets/json/data.json***

```
{
 // X contenido data.json
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los proveedores tienen Http incluido de forma predeterminada, y con el fin de utilizar Http en su aplicación tendrá que agregar el HttpModule a su app.module.ts:[1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-provider-for-http-error-in-ionic-2/85762)

Comment: Gracias, parece ser correcta la respuesta, pero podría contestarla completamente, agregando lo que falta al código